# GAE automatic scaling

Tags: google-app-engine

I have problem with automatic scaling at GAE.

One of my application module have instance class F4 and folowing automatic scaling settings.

```
<automatic-scaling>
    <min-idle-instances>2</min-idle-instances>
    <max-idle-instances>5</max-idle-instances>
    <min-pending-latency>automatic</min-pending-latency>
    <max-pending-latency>30ms</max-pending-latency>
    <max-concurrent-requests>100</max-concurrent-requests>
</automatic-scaling>
```

I set maximum instances as 5 but when we run some jmeter tests with 300 users running instance number is increased to more than 40.
So it's looks that GAE don't handle this parameter correctly.
Does anybody have experience with this problem?

Comment: That's because you set IDLE instances, which is the number of instances always running when you have NO to a small number of requests. It's up to GAE to decide when it needs a new instance for proper handling of all requests.

Comment: You could increase **min-pending-latency** setting and make sure **multi-threading** is enabled to reduce the number of instances (in addition to optimizing code).

Comment: It's also worth making sure your JMeter test plan simulates a realistic traffic profile. For the App Engine scheduler, there's a big difference between a burst of 300 threads and a steady state of 300 users. 40 instances with 300 users suggests your response latency is quite high.  We've managed >1000 concurrent users on between 5 and 10 instances, depending on the nature of the requests.

Comment: The whole point of automatic scaling is to always have enough instances to run smoothly. If you truly want a hard cap look at Basic scaling https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY wanted to use the max instances cap, you have to use the app engine Application Settings UI at appengine.google.com.  You can't set the max instances in app.yaml (yet).